# How to create iPad native looking html help pages?

Tags: iphone, ipad, dashcode

I'd like to make some in-app help for my iPad app so I'm looking for examples of other apps that do it well. If I look the help for the Apple Pages app on my iPad, it opens the following url:
http://help.apple.com/iwork/mobile/interface/#tan724868a9

This looks like a native app in Safari on iPad. How did Apple make their html help page look like that? Is this simply a dashcode implementation or is there some other way to display native looking help via html in an iPad app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just HTML/CSS/Javascript, but you could take a look at [jQTouch](http://jqtouch.com) for something similar, or the just-announced [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/2010/08/announcing-the-jquery-mobile-project/).